# Cos'è il "trombonismo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Probabilmente Elda pensava di dover salvare Gheri dalla sua anima qualunquista. E Gheri pensava che avrebbe potuto far qualcosa per arginare l'inevitabile *trombonismo* verso cui vedeva andare Elda.

Ho cercato il significato di "trombonismo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vedi il significato c. nella voce [*trombone*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trombone/) del dizionario Treccani:

> Persona (spec. oratore, scrittore, o intellettuale in genere) piena di sé, che si esprime in modo enfatico e retorico, esagerando la propria importanza e servendosi di parole ricercate ma vacue (e analogam., di attore che recita con enfasi esagerata); comune spec. l’espressione vecchio trombone. Anche, chi abitualmente assume toni da smargiasso; spaccone.

La parola “trombonismo” (coniata lì per lì, direi) può significare l'atteggiamento o stato dell'essere trombone.